# How to convert Unicode to bytes in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, type-conversion

I have the following code to convert unicode to bytes, it works:

```
    byte[] emojiBytes = new byte[]{(byte)0xF0,(byte)0x9F,(byte)0x98,(byte)0x81};
    String emojiAsString = new String(emojiBytes,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    // JButton button = new JButton("<html>" + emojiAsString + "</html>");
    JButton button = new JButton(emojiAsString);
```

But what if I only know the unicode like this : `1F601` , `1F603`, I want to convert symbols on this page : https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Given a string like `1F601`, how do I convert it to `\xF0\x9F\x98\x81` then to `new byte[]{(byte)0xF0,(byte)0x9F,(byte)0x98,(byte)0x81}`?

So to simplify, my code would look like this:

```
JButton getButton(String unicodeText)
{
    JButton aButton= // how to convert ???

    return aButton;
}
```

Then I call it like this: `JButton myButton=getButton("1F601");`

Comment: so you want to [convert hex string to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex string gives a hex number which is a Unicode code point; that then needs to be converted to UTF-8. The trouble is that the code point exceeds 0xFFFF, which means it's not directly representable as a Java char.

After a little research, here is one quick and dirty test program.

Character.toChars converts to a char array
with which we construct a String;

getBytes() then converts that to UTF-8 bytes.

Even though the String uses UTF-16, the subsequent conversion treats the single character as a whole (which is required by standard, actually).

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class Z {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cp = 0x1f601;
        byte b[] = new String(Character.toChars(cp)).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for (int k=0; k<b.length; k++) 
              System.out.printf(" %x ", b[k]);
        System.out.println();
     }
}
```

The output is:

```
$ java Z
 f0  9f  98  81
```

Comment: It is implicitly assumed that converting the String "1f601" to an int 1f601 does not need explanation.

Comment: Seems it solved half the problem, could you take a string input like "1F601" and generate an output of "new byte[]{(byte)0xF0,(byte)0x9F,(byte)0x98,(byte)0x81}" ? I tried this which didn't work : int cp = Integer.parseInt("1f601")

Comment: It's hexadecimal -- ```Integer.parseInt("1f601", 16)```